# Suppose $f(z) \in H(D)$ is it possible to have...

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

(a) Suppose $f(z) \in H(D)$ is it possible to have $$|f^{(n)}(0)| \ge e^n *n!$$
for infinitely many n?

(b) Suppose there is a constant M such that $$|f^{(n)}(0)| \le M^n$$ for all n sufficiently large. Show that $f(z)$ can be extended to all of $C$ as an entire function.

My thinking:
I am having trouble grasping what is going on here for example how can $|f^{(n)}(0)| \le e^n$ essentially from part (b) but the be greater than $e^n *n!$ something doesn't seem to add up to me.

Comment: Any information on $D$ ?

Comment: @C.Dubussy sry no information on $D$. I am reading through a complex analysis boor and it is in the section about arcs and discs if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is that on any disk centered at the origin where the function is analytic you have
$$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} {f^{(n)}(0) \over n!} z^n$$ 
So for a), you could pick any $z$ for which $|ez| > 1$ and you can see the above series must diverge.

For b), the above series converges uniformly on any disk centered at the origin by the estimate you are given, and the resulting function is analytic. It must equal $f(z)$ on $D$ since $f(z)$ is equal to its power series there.